# how to deploy existing azure function using terraform

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have an azure function created using visual studio locally. I am trying to deploy the azure function using terraform but it is throwing an error

The code that i am trying is shown below :

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "testDeployTF" {
  name                      = "testDeployADddecendant"
  location                  = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg-testDeployTF.location}"
  resource_group_name       = "${azurerm_resource_group.rg-testDeployTF.name}"
  app_service_plan_id       = "${azurerm_app_service_plan.sp-testDeployTF.id}"
  storage_connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=xxxx;AccountKey=xxxxxxxxxxx;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"

  app_settings {
    HASH            = "${base64sha256(file("FunctionApp1.zip"))}"
    WEBSITE_USE_ZIP = "https://${decendant.sa-testDeployTF.name}.blob.core.windows.net/${azurerm_storage_container.sc-testDeployTF.name}/${azurerm_storage_blob.sb-testDeployTF.name}${data.azurerm_storage_account_sas.sas-testDeployTF.sas}"

  }
}
```

If i remove the app_setting the code creates a new empty function but what i want is i need a new function with the code that i have it in my local.

The above code throws the below error when i use app_seettings :

Error: Unsupported block type

on terraformscript.tf line 78, in resource "azurerm_function_app" "testDeployTF":
  78:   app_settings {

Blocks of type "app_settings" are not expected here.

Comment: Do i need to put app_settings in variable.tf?

Comment: I do not think you can use terraform to create the function with code inside in one step.

Comment: @CharlesXu how do you do then. Basically i have an azure function created via visual studio and i want this function to be deployed to the azure portal using terraform

Comment: When you use visual studio, it uses the extension such as azure-function-core-tool to copy the code for you. And terraform just can create the function for you. You need to copy your code to the function yourself.

Comment: @CharlesXu i want this to be automated so what could be the easiest way to paste the code? I have the code uploaded in the blob.

Comment: is it possible to upload using azure cli commands ?? after using the terraform

Comment: Yes, you can do it through the CLI.

Comment: @CharlesXu how can you brief me. What i will do is i will create the function using terraform and then using CLI i will upload the code. Can you help me with the commands. I have zipped the whole visual studio project and uploaded in blob so i want it to be taken from blob and then the code to be pasted to function

Comment: @charles Xu I am still trying . But how do I using cli deploy the code to the function  which is there in the blob

Comment: As I know, it's impossible when you store the code in the storage blob through the CLI. You also need to download the code from the blob.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your issue, you just can use Terraform to create an empty Azure Function, do not with your code. Also, when you use the visual studio locally, it creates the empty function for you, then uses the azure-function-core-tool to copy the code for you.

You can take look at the details about the [azure-function-core-tool](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools). And when you use the Azure CLI, it also needs to use the tool, see the steps in [Create your first function from the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-first-azure-function-azure-cli).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this question googling the terraform error. You can simply add an equal sign after `app_settings`.

```
app_settings = {
  Key = "Value"
}
```